# Adding First Login to SQL Azure Database

Tags: azure-sql-database, user-management

I'm trying to create a SQL Azure database. While the database successfully gets created, I can't login to it. The reason why is, I don't know what the default username / password is. Or, how to create the first user that can access the database.

There has to be something basic I'm missing here. How do I create the first user for a SQL Azure database.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The database exists on an Azure SQL Instance.  You need the administrative loginid/password you assigned when you created the instance.

When you are in the Azure Management Portal (https://manage.windowsazure.com) go to "SQL DATABASES".

On the "DATABASES" page (along the top), find your database.  Look for the name of your databases' server in the "SERVER" column, and click on the link for the server.

[image: Azure SQL Databases in Azure Management Portal]

On the page for the server, along the right side under "quick glance", you will see the "ADMINISTRATOR LOGIN" and further up you see a link to "Reset Administrator Password".  You can reset it if you don't remember it.

[image: Azure SQL Server Login Credentials]

Now, you can login using those credentials (admin login/pwd) and create additional logins as needed.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for this!  However, this information is now very out of date.  The old portal does not seem to show our sql databases and I cannot find anything in the new portal to see or reset the database password.  Any ideas?